# MVC dbml and weborb for .net performance

Tags: .net, apache-flex, model-view-controller, weborb

We have a flex application that runs along side a mvc .net application. Our flex app communicates with .net via Weborb. We recently put our entire database schema into a single dbml file. Previously we had the database schema split out into several dbmls. The problem we have run into since consolodating into one dbml is that our weborb calls in the flex are taking 300 to 400 ms longer than they did when we had several dbmls.

This doesn't seem to make sense to us at all. Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Were only the WebOrb calls affected?  Add some logging to find out exactly where the slowdown occurred.  If logging isn't sufficient, try a profiler.  red-gate makes a great one, ants.  http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

- Are you logging to the database?
- Do you have a lot of concurrent calls to weborb from Flex? Having multiple db's can speed up things if you have concurrent calls.
- Do you use weborb authentication?
- Have you checked whether weborb is the problem? Run some tests where you call a service from a .NET Unit Test and then call the same service from a Flex Unit Test. Maybe the delay hasn't got anything to do with WebORB.